# How to do jump to register indirect in nasm 64 bit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I've the following nasm code in a 32 bit program ( a Forth interpreter)

```
    MOV     EBP, LONG[USINI+(CW*(3))]    ;Return stack
    ...
    LODSD                  ; NEXT
    JMP      LONG[EAX]
```

The last instruction fetches an address from where AX points to and jumps to that address.
The equivalent code in 64 bits doesn't assemble any more:

```
    MOV     RBP, QWORD[USINI+(CW*(3))]    ;Return stack
    ...
    LODSD                  ; NEXT
    JMP      QWORD[RAX]
```

What is the correct way to specify this instruction in NASM 64 bits?
Of course it may be a defect in nasm, but how could I establish that?

(The exact same code assembles to good effect in fasm.)

(The first QWORD is accepted by nasm)

The message is:"ci86.lina64.asm:318: error: impossible combination of address sizes"
318 is the line with JMP.

The nasm version is:NASM version 2.10.01 compiled on Jun 14 2012

Leaving out "QWORD" gives the same error message and in addition:
"ci86.lina64.asm:318: error: impossible combination of address sizes"

Comment: `jmp [rax]` is a 64 bit jump since all indirect jumps are 64 bit. You don't need the `qword` even though it does work. It's unclear whether you wan't `jmp rax` or `jmp [rax]` though. You also forgot to post nasm version and the error you get.

Comment: I only get that error if I try to assemble as 32 bit. Are you sure you used 64 bit properly?

Comment: Right on the spot, Jester. I forgot to start with "BITS 64". With all those QWORDS accepted, I was totally blocked to think in that direction.

Comment: Voting to close as "typographical error", if that's all it was.

Comment: This was a tricky problem that took me a lot of time. Dismissing it as a mere typographical error deprives people from learning what kind of situations can result from omitting a BITS 64 keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jester points out

```
jmp [rax]
```

is correct, while

```
jmp qword[rax]
```

is allowed.
If it fails you're doing wrong something else.

In this case the problem was the missing

BITS 64

keyword.

In order to get a 64 bit object file you need to specify -felf64 as the architecture in the commandline invoking nasm like so

nasm x.asm -felf64 -g -o x.o

In that case the BITS 64 is implied. The problem is of course that you'll never get past assembling and can't discover that mistake.

Comment: You don't need it if you assemble with `-felf64`: that object file format implies `bits 64`.

Answer (score 2):

First, `jmp [mem]` is a memory-indirect jump (set RIP = a pointer loaded from memory).  `jmp rax` would be a register-indirect jump, setting `RIP = RAX`.

You didn't say which line is line 318.  Are you sure it's the `jmp`?  Because there doesn't look like anything wrong with the syntax on that line.

Is your code still using 32bit pointers in 64bit mode?  That's possible, as long as you stick to the low 4GB of address space so addresses fit in 32b.  Changing that would require re-sizing all the data structures that store pointers.

Be aware that stack addresses are *not* in the low 32b by default.  Using the 32bit address-size prefix (e.g. `mov rdx, [eax]`) sign-extends the address.

```
MOV     EBP, QWORD[USINI+(CW*(3))]    ; you probably need RBP, or else this should still be a 32bit load.  If it's 64bit, I hope you fixed the address calculations to account for each element being wider.
...
LODSD                  ; This a 32bit load, zeroing the upper32 of RAX.
JMP      QWORD[RAX]
```

Do you need to increment `rsi`, or could you have just used `mov  eax, [rsi]` before the jmp?  `lodsd` and `lodsq` are only 2 uops on Intel, so they're actually not a bad choice if you do need both effects.

Comment: Surely  the code is as intended. This is a mature Forth interpreter (2001, 64-bits since 2008), with dozens of programs that have solved projecteuler.net problems, sometimes running for days.

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst: So you're not porting it to 64bits?  I thought from the question phrasing that you were.  Are you borrowing chunks of its code for your own project?  I don't understand what changed that made it "stop working".

Comment: I've a system that through m4 can generate the same assembly code for different assemblers (nasm gas tasm masm and my favorite: fasm). The code generated by gas and fasm passed all regression tests. The code for nasm didn't assemble, this one instruction being refused. So if you would call this porting then I was porting working 64 bits assembler code from one  assembler to an other.

Comment: The code is as intended mostly, but you correctly pointed at the EBP. It is not relevant to the question but indeed it must be RBP. I've corrected it.